# The item you have requested is not available for purchase

Tags: android, android-billing

I am trying to test subscriptions in android app. I use dungeons example. I uploaded apk which is not published, but subscription items are published. I added new test account(gmail) in dev console which is not developer account. I reseted phone to factory and added test account. I installed signed apk(same version as uploaded).

When I try purchase I get "The item you have requested is not available for purchase" but I see in background item which I requested.

Some thoughts what can be problem here? Thanks

Comment: hii...
i have facing same problem ..
do let me know how you cleared it....

Comment: well, wait some time (few hours) after upload. Then I was able to make it work with dungeons example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this link and refer table 1. I also faced this problem.http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html#billing-testing-static

Have a look at that table than u will get that whats going wrong in your table.

Answer (score 1):

Same thing happened to me when I tested in-app billing, and there was no other way to overcome it but to actually publish the application. Once the application had "replicated" to Google servers (which took several hours, during which I got yet another obscure error message when trying to purchase anything), buying subscriptions worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. After changing the APK state from unpublished to Activate (in APK files tab) and waiting for 1 hour or so, the product ID could be purchased.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to upload the signed APK to developer console.

Make sure to install the signed APK on your device not launch the app in the debugger.

Make sure to create a test account in your developer console.

Make sure to sign in your device with your test account.

Make sure to create in app billing in your developer console and finally activate the item from the console!!! (this is the one that got me after fully following google's tutorial)